# Need to convert my HTML5 based web application into a mobile app which will target all mobile devices

Tags: html

Is it possible to convert my existing HTML/jquery.js website into a mobile app that targets all device (iPhone, Android, Blackberry, etc.). Below are the points I can think of. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Add jquerymobile.js and change the css style (based on the device which is accessing your site).

What all points should I consider while converting my existing desktop based website into a mobile one. Or should I start creating a mobile website (MVC4 mobile website) from scratch? If that is the case then I have to maintain 2 code bases (1 for desktop and 1 for mobile) which I don't want to do.

Comment: For me, I try gonative.io and it works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may avoid the need for two code bases if you design your Web app in a device-agnostic way. That means that it can be displayed on many different screen sizes (anything from small mobile phones to plasma TV sets) and navigated using many different input methods (mice, keyboards, touch screens, game pads, etc.). Various techniques to do that are nowadays known as "mobile first" or "responsive design". For a good start, see:

- [Creating a Mobile-First Responsive Web Design](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/)
- [320 and Up - the ‘tiny screen first’ responsive boilerplate](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/)
- [Mobile HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile)
- the [Responsive Mobile First template](http://verekia.com/initializr/responsive-template) from [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/)
- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- For more see: [Nice intro to Web Design frameworks](https://twitter.com/pocztarski/status/546009375543132162) (a video by [Edreih Aldana](http://www.ealdana.com/))

Keep in mind that it may not always be possible or convenient if your application is very complicated and in the end you may end up with two (or more) code bases in that case, but most of the websites and Web apps can be built using those principles in mind.

Also keeping in mind the [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/glance/) can make it much easier to design websites that can work on many devices and with many input methods.

You haven't specifically asked for this but additionally you can use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to convert mobile websites or Web apps to actual native mobile applications for iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, Palm WebOS, Bada and Symbian, so you can have your apps available for installation from various app stores for those particular platforms.

## Update 2016

I wrote this answer in 2012 and some relevant tools have been developed since then:

- [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) - a hybrid mobile app framework based on [Angular](https://angularjs.org/)
- [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) - a framework to build native apps based on [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)
- [Framework7](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/) - a hybrid mobile app framework based on [Dom7](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/dom.html) (similar to jQuery)
- [Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk) (formerly known as appMobi)
- [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)
- [AppGyver](http://www.appgyver.com/)
- [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/)
- [Onsen UI](https://onsen.io/)
- More at the [Mobile Frameworks Comparison Chart](http://mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart.com/)

Comment: React Native is not Hybrid :)

Comment: @IanSegers You're right. Thanks. I updated the answer.

Comment: Intel XDK is discontinued.

Answer (score 5):

This question was asked 3 years ago and has good answers, I just want to add some info, based on my experience:

It's better not create separate mobile design, but modify existing web with responsive web design using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Then you have two options:

1. Create Hybrid Web App using [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), it's almost the same as PhoneGap, mentioned above.
   I'm using Visual Studio, so I used [VS project template](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-vs.aspx).
2. Hosted Web App using [Manifoldjs](http://www.manifoldjs.com/).
   I thinks this option is easy, you just take your existing web site and wrap it, creating Web App.

And if you use Visual Studio, you can create [hosted Web App even without Manifilod](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/create-a-hosted-app/).

Answer (score 3):

You can try [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), a fast way to deploy your app to various kinds of devices.

Comment: The PhoneGap Build service is discontinued since October 1, 2020.

Answer (score 2):

Try the free [phonegap build service](https://build.phonegap.com). You upload your html stuff, and it will automatically generate apps for different devices!

Comment: The PhoneGap Build service is discontinued since October 1, 2020.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Appery.io to easily build a web app.  Here is an article that shows you how to make an iOS app from your website. If your website is responsive, it will automatically target all mobile screen sizes. http://www.techlivewire.com/4844/generate-an-iphone-app-for-your-website.html