# building an web app, that should be converted to mobile app?

Tags: mobile, web-applications

I am building an webapp, like a normal webpage with html, css, javascript - and php/mariadb for the backend.

When it is done, I also want an mobile app, containing the same features. Is it possible to convert my webapp to mobile app both for android and ios, without rewriting all my code? Or is their some framework or language, that is better to use then others?

Any pointers much appriciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to convert my HTML5 based web application into a mobile app which will target all mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608371/need-to-convert-my-html5-based-web-application-into-a-mobile-app-which-will-targ)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are frameworks that allow you to create cross platform apps, like Flutter (Dart language) or React Native (JavaScript language). You can run it on various operating systems.